# How or where can I get Android's native launcher in Android Studio?

Tags: android, launcher

I'm trying to build my own launcher, but I would like a base. I can't seem to find out how or where to get the launcher code into Android Studio so that I can build off of it.

Can anyone tell me where to get the latest launcher base for 6.0?

Comment: Most of Android is open source on Github. Have you searched there? There is no "template" Launcher project in Android Studio

Comment: Ok, checked, so far its ok.. @cricket_007

Comment: I assume you found this one?  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+refs

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope, this one: https://github.com/fookwood/Launcher3 also can you check my new thread? i need a bit more help too